# How to find the coefficient of $x^4y^4$ in $(x+y)^2(x^3+y^3)^6$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, multinomial-coefficients

$(x+y)^2(x^3+y^3)^6 = (x^2+2xy+y^2)(x^3+y^3)^6 = (x^2+2xy+y^2)(...+Ax^2y^4+Bx^4y^2+Cx^3y^3)$. Clearly both $A$ and $B$ are zero, and $C$ is the coefficient of $x^3y^3$ in $(x^3+y^3)^6$, which is 6!

But then the coefficent of $x^4y^4$ in $(x+y)^2(x^3+y^3)^6$ would be $2*6!$ which is way too big.

Comment: It is zero$\phantom{}$.

Comment: This is same as finding the coefficient of $x^2y^2$ in $$(x+y)(x^3+y^3)^3$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee which is still zero. I presume that Sid wanted to ask a somewhat different question, but only he can tell us what that is.

Comment: How do you find the coefficient of $x^3y^3$ in $(x^3+y^3)^6$?

Comment: @SidCaroline The coefficient of $x^3y^3$ in $(x^3+y^3)^6$ is zero, as $(x^3+y^3)^6$ is homogeneous of degree $18$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0$  because a degree of $x^4y^4$ is $8$, but $\deg{(x+y)^2(x^3+y^3)^6}=20$
and $(x+y)^2(x^3+y^3)^6$ is homogeneous.

Comment: And the product is a homogeneous polynomial.

Comment: @Bernard Yes! Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just need to say, *Merry Christmas, Michael!* just because of the Christmas hat :)))

Comment: Marry Christmas to you!